# Get match groups values off Ruby regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

just a newbie to Ruby here:

Tried similar code today as below:

```
m = /(.*)xyz(.*)/.match("abcxyzdef")
```

subsequently ruby will set global variables $1 = “abc" and $2 = “def"
but if code is like

```
str1 = $1
str1.gsub!('a', '0')
str2 = $2
```

in this case, str2 will NOT be able to get value from match groups `str2=nil`, unless

```
str1 = $1 
str2 = $2
str1.gsub!('a', '0')
```

so just curious what magic is behind this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gsub`, like `match` uses the regex engine and thus overwrites the $1, $2 variables. If you want access to the data stored in those variables, you need to store them in a temporary variable before excecuting another regex method.

```
result = [$1, $2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can always use the match return value (you even assign it to `m`):

```
str1 = m[1]
# => "abc"
str1.gsub!('a', '0')
# => "0bc"
str2 = m[2]
# => "def"
```

Answer (score 0):

As @UriAgassi suggested, I would prefer to access the MatchData object returned by `match` because it is less cryptic than the `$0`, …, `$9` global variables. However, I tend to like the block form of `match` better, because it makes it clear what regex the matches belong to.

```
/(.*)xyz(.*)/.match("abcxyzdef") do |m|
  str1, str2 = m.captures
  str1.gsub!('a', '0')
end
```